# php variable in jquery function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a php function and in this php function I am trying to implement an API call using jQuery. I could not use PHP for this because of some restrictions so I need to use jQuery in this function. I added my jquery code inside PHP function which is working correctly for static data. But I do not know how I should pass PHP variables in data. Any suggestion regarding this will be appreciated.
Here is my code for jQuery

```
var settings = {
"url": "MY_URL_TO_CREATE_USER_ACCOUNT",
"method": "POST",
"timeout": 0,
"headers": {
    "external-token": "MY_TOKEN",
    "Content-Type": ["application/json", "text/plain"]
},
"data": "{\r\n\"UserName\": \"user6\",\r\n\"FirstName\": \"F_NAME\",\r\n\"Password\": \"user6_pass\",\r\n\"LastName\": \"L_NAME\",\r\n\"Subscription\": \"Full\",\r\n\"ExpireDate\": \"2020-11-08\"\r\n}",
};

jQuery.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

This code works for static data but I do not know how to pass php variables for the data attribute.

Comment: This code seems insecure to me because it’s unexpected to have a password stored in the JavaScript so it might get cached in places you don’t want it to be.

Comment: Good point and you are right but we can only pass data using JavaScript. So my main object is to pass this data to the API server.

Comment: What about you put the value of the PHP variable into an input field then get value of the field in jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

More proper solution would be using form.data for this.

Probably not the best solution, but try this,

1. Echo out the variable and assign it to javascript variable
2. Use that variable in the data attribute

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Store the value of your PHP variable in a field then get the value of the field via jQuery.

```
<?php

$settings = '{
"url": "MY_URL_TO_CREATE_USER_ACCOUNT",
"method": "POST",
"timeout": 0,
"headers": {
"external-token": "MY_TOKEN",
"Content-Type": ["application/json", "text/plain"]
},
"data": "{\r\n\"UserName\": \"user6\",\r\n\"FirstName\": \"F_NAME\",\r\n\"Password\": \"user6_pass\",\r\n\"LastName\": \"L_NAME\",\r\ \"Subscription\": \"Full\",\r\n\"ExpireDate\": \"2020-11-08\"\r\n}",
};';
echo "<textarea style='display:none' id='some_data'>$settings</textarea>";

//Then your jQuery
var settings = $("#some_data").val();
jQuery.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
console.log(response);
});
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass `PHP` variable to `SCRIPT` by echo

```
<?php

$data_to_pass = //Your Dynamic data

?>

<script>

    var settings = {
        "url": "MY_URL_TO_CREATE_USER_ACCOUNT",
        "method": "POST",
        "timeout": 0,
        "headers": {
            "external-token": "MY_TOKEN",
            "Content-Type": ["application/json", "text/plain"]
        },
        "data": <?php echo json_encode($data_to_pass); ?>;
    }

    jQuery.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
       console.log(response);
    });    

<script>
```

Comment: I tried json_encode function but using this I am getting internal server error in API response.

Comment: @wpdd seems JSON SUPPORT is not enabled. You can check with phpinfo().

Comment: Okay I checked this and I can see that json support is enabled.

Comment: @wpdd are you using any framework? Also share full code if possible.

Comment: I am using WordPress and I am trying to implement this in theme file.

Comment: @wpdd share your php file which contains  js integration.